# How to create unit test of webservice which add key value in database

Tags: c#, xunit

That is my code which i want to test it:

```
    public async Task AddKeyAsync(Key privateKey)
    {
        privateKey.Value = this.EncryptKey(privateKey.Value);

        this._db.Keys.Add(privateKey);
        await this._db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: what specifically is your concern? Do you need general advice on creating unit tests, or have you got a particular problem with how to test this one? It's unclear.

Comment: You should be more specific about the technology you use, better if you provide version, platform etc. Webservice is a general term and can be many things . Anyway  As far as I see it is about .net core webapi code.  Theoretically it is possible to do that. You can mock db with a simple in memory db implementation of your own and use that in a unit test. But testing against a real db is strongly discouraged. Because unit tests should be independent, granular. In unit tests business logic inside code should be targeted. This kind of tests are usually inside scope of integration testing.

Comment: @ADyson i have a practical problem

Comment: Ok. Do we have to guess what the problem is, then? I think it might be quicker if you just tell us... :-)

Comment: Just need help how to create unit test for the concrete code